# Cross-compiler cant see shared library

Tags: linux, gcc, shared-libraries, cross-compiling

I have successfully cross compiled a C project for a microcontroller from my Linux machine. The compiler needed some shared library which I have carefully placed in /opt/foo-folder. With the same care, I have set permissions for foo-folder so that it can be fully accessed.

Despite all this, I cannot cross compile any C file without sudo access. I assume that this can be a file ownership problem, yet I have set the current user (which is also admin) to be the owner of foo-folder.
It is not stopping me to do what I want, but it is very annoying.

Any advice or suggestion is welcomed. And please keep in mind that I am a rather average Linux user.

Comment: If compiling for a microcontroller, you probably need to statically link *everything*.... unless your definition of MCU is very different than mine.  Assuming you *are* statically linking, you can just specify the path of the library (.a file) in the link command the same way you would an object file.  No need to place the library in `/opt/`.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland quite a reasonable point. Thanks.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland, just out of curiosity: is static linking preferred mainly for avoiding CPU overhead?

Comment: When you say microcontroller, it makes me think relatively small processor running all its code from an on-board flash/ROM and on-board RAM both measured in kilobytes, not gigabytes.  ARM Cortex-Mx stuff for example.  If that's the case, static linking is the *only* option because you don't have a dynamic linker (or traditional OS) available on the platform.  If you're talking about something running something like Linux, BSD, or QNX for the OS, then you can dynamically link.  When you have the option to do either, there are plenty of trade-offs to consider.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer. I had a slightly misunderstanding of this,  because I thought any embedded system (even running an OS) can be called a MCU. I will keep that in mind. I've also realized that there are multiple factors to consider when deciding between static and dynamic linking (when possible).

Comment: MCU is not necessarily inaccurate, just not the most common term.   Microcontroller originally meant a processor with built-in peripherals or memory to distinguish it from a microprocessor that's only external interfaces are memory buses and interrupt lines. Older MCUs were for embedded systems like industrial controllers but today are everywhere. Over time, microprocessors grew into what we know today as CPUs (like in a PC). Add a peripherals to a processor designed for a modern OS and you get a system-on-chip (SoC) commonly found in phones, tablets, cars radios, etc.